# What's the correct Code Signing setting for the Debug build config in Xcode 4?

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4, certificate, provisioning

Under the "Code Signing" section in Build Settings I have "Debug" set to "Don't Code Sign", and the indented line below it "Any iOS SDK" set to the "iPhone Developer" value.

When I build and run, Xcode tells me:

> warning: Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was
>   invalid, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate.
>   (-19011)

The point is, I'm using the Debug configuration! Anyways, so I changed this to the Distribution Certificate, but now Xcode thorws an error that there is no valid Ad-Hoc Distribution Provisioning Profile on my device. Of course there is not, because I just want to develop as usual.

Previously I had installed the Distribution Certificate. That's where the mess began.

Did anyone else encounter this problem and found a solution how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You could create Developer Certificate and developer profile. Don't use Ad-Hoc Distribution Provisioning Profile at debug. Please check your Developer Certificate.

Comment: I don't have to create it. It's already there. Worked a couple of months with my Developer Certificate without any issue. Until I submitted my app.

Comment: There are some issues with profiles. You could create new developer profile and choose it. It takes two minutes. Do you use push notifications?

Answer (score 0):

This is the same exact error you get when submitting an app(building as an archive and using the distribution profile) It would be helpful if you posted a screenshot of your `Build Settings` for both your **target** and your **project** as there are many things that could be wrong. But it seems like the main problem is your code signing.